# Inserting a dataframe row into another dataframe using the name of the index value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Basically the middle image shows the current values after all iterations are complete. I tried many ways to try to update the index "0" to be the particular ConfigurationLevel_ value e.g. CongigurationLevel_1 but I have had no success. While I'm able to create a dataframe with the correct index values, I'm not able to get the actual values in them. I'm guessing that a solution would solve both ways, that I need to find out how to get:

Combined_SHAP_df[ConfigurationLevel_i] = SHAP_Level_df[0]

(I have SHAP_Level_df[0] as each dataframe created only has a single row).

```
ConfigurationList = []
    for i in range(OutputDim):
        ConfigurationList.append("ConfigurationLevel_" + str(i + 1))

Combined_SHAP_df = pd.DataFrame(index=ConfigurationList)
Combined_SHAP_df = pd.concat([Combined_SHAP_df, SHAP_Level_df])
```

where SHAP_Level_df is a single row in a dataframe (this is in a loop so these are continually produced and concatenated.

[image: SHAP_Level_df contents]

This is the issue:

[image: Assigning row values to an named index]

Whereas the final product would look like this:

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you try to accomplish. Put what you have and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a dataframe with the index names initially create the basic dataframe without indexes:

```
Combined_SHAP_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

and after the dataframe has been completely filled with values, ie. after the loop containing:

```
Combined_SHAP_df = pd.concat([Combined_SHAP_df, SHAP_Level_df])
```

as the number of rows of Combined_SHAP_df will be equal to the number of index names we can set the .index names to the list of names:

```
Combined_SHAP_df.index = ConfigurationList
```

This just replaces all of the index values with the new values.